# How can I write a better xpath expression?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have html similar to this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span>
      <span class = "x28w"></span>
    </span>
  <td>
    <span>
      <a>
        <span>3899393</span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <span>
    </span>
  <td>
    <span>
      <a>
        <span>3899394</span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

So basically the first span is blank but will show an icon if there is a sub span underneath it with class `"x28w"`.   The second one (i.e. `3899393`) is a case number.

I want to write a selenium method in Java  `List<String>getCasesWithAlert()`.

I can do a `findElements(By.xpath("//tr"))`, loop through the elements, check if there is a `td/span/span[contains(@class,'x28w')]` for the current tr.

If there is then take the row, find child td elements, get the second one and find the element a/span and then get text.  But this is a bit complicated.

Is there some kind of xpath expression I can use (like following-sibling or something) to find the cases containing alert icons (class x28w) in one expression?

Answer (score 0):

For every `tr` you can check if the first `td` meets the criteria and get the desired `span` element from the second `td`:

```
//tr[td[1][span/span[contains(@class,'x28w')]]]/td[2]/span/a/span
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is actually inside more html so instead of tr it is
//div[contains(@id,'t1::db') or contains(@id,'t2::db') ]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr" but I assume I can just extrapolate your path, right?

Comment: @user3257891 yup, the idea stays the same, I've used the HTML you've provided for testing - worked for me. Let me know what your real HTML code is if you'll have difficulties applying the solution. Thanks.

Comment: How about getting the inverse?  The ones that don't have the x28w?  Then there is not that second x28w.  I can't use span[not contains ... because there won't be the inner span.